# Meaning: improvement in RMSE during crossvalidation, although not on testset?

Tags: r, neural-network

In the code below I train a NN with crossvalidation on the first 20000 records in the dataset. The dataset contains 8 predictors.

First I have split my data in 2 parts:
the first 20.000 rows (trainset)
and the last 4003 rows (out of sample test set)

I have done 2 runs:
run 1) a run with 3 predictors
run 2) a run with all 8 predictors (see code below).

Based on crossvalidation within the 20.000 rows from the trainset, the RMSE (for the optimal parametersetting) improves from 2.30 (run 1) to 2.11 (run 2).

Although when I test both models on the 4003 rows from the out of sample test set, the RMSE improves only neglible from 2.64 (run 1) to 2.63 (run 2).

What can be concluded from these contradiction in the results?

Thanks!

```
### R code from Applied Predictive Modeling (2013) by Kuhn and Johnson.
### Chapter 7: Non-Linear Regression Models
### Required packages: AppliedPredictiveModeling, caret, doMC (optional), 
### earth, kernlab, lattice, nnet
################################################################################

library(caret)    
### Load the data

mydata <- read.csv(file="data.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")

validatiex <- mydata[20001:24003,c(1:8)]
validatiey <- mydata[20001:24003,9]

mydata <-  mydata[1:20000,]

x <- mydata[,c(1:8)]
y <- mydata[,9]

parti <- createDataPartition(y, times = 1, p=0.8, list = FALSE)    
x_train <- x[parti,]
x_test <- x[-parti,]
y_train <- y[parti]
y_test <- y[-parti]


set.seed(100)
indx <- createFolds(y_train, returnTrain = TRUE)
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", index = indx)

## train neural net:

nnetGrid <- expand.grid(decay = c(.1), 
                        size = c(5, 15, 30), 
                        bag = FALSE)

set.seed(100)
nnetTune <- train(x = x_train, y = y_train,
                  method = "avNNet",
                  tuneGrid = nnetGrid,
                  trControl = ctrl,
                  preProc = c("center", "scale"),
                  linout = TRUE,
                  trace = FALSE,
                  MaxNWts = 30 * (ncol(x_train) + 1) + 30 + 1,
                  maxit = 1000,
                  repeats = 25,
                  allowParallel = FALSE)
nnetTune
plot(nnetTune)



predictions <- predict(nnetTune, validatiex, type="raw")
mse <- mean((validatiey - predictions)^2)
mse <- sqrt(mse)
print (mse)
```

Comment: I would first try to run repeated CV `trainControl(method = "cv", number = 3, repeat = 5)` and see if the CV results are more in line with the validation results.

Comment: Thanks. It says 'repeats` has no meaning for this resampling method. Just increase number?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, the method should be "repeatedcv".

Comment: @ missuse the RMSE on the trainset remain almost the same: 2.29 (was 2.30) and 2.11 (2.11). The validation results are now: 2.65 (2.64) and 2.59 (2.63). Did you expect the validation result to change? Indeed the contradiction is smaller now, although the imrovement is still larger for the training results than for the validation results.